# Chrome show code rather than python print content

Tags: python, html, google-chrome

I find a sample code in "programming python", whose output is different from my test.

My platform is Ubuntu + python 2.7.

In the html, a POST request is made:

```
<form method=POST action="test.py">
```

In test.py, a HTTP response is made like this:

```
print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
print '<title>Reply Page</title>'
print 'Who are you?'
```

After form submission in HTML page, chrome displays code of text.py rather than a html page. However the book shows the output as a html page.

Is the book wrong?

Comment: Nope, but it made assumptions which may or may not have been actually stated (since I don't have that book).  You need to be running the test.py code as a cgi-bin or similar program.  Are you running the applications in apache or some other web server?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on UNIX execution bit on `test.py`
Start it `test.py` with line

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
```

And then run UNIX command

```
   chmod u+x test.py
```

This turns to file to executable UNIX script.

Also you might need to change your web server settings to allow the execution of cgi-bin style scripts.